# Can datatable not count the hidden row into the total result?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatable

I am using the jquery plugin datatable

https://datatables.net/

And I would like to hide some row during the process,

```
   $(".menu_time_table tbody tr").hide();

            $.each(obj, function (i, v) {
                if (v.user_type === "2") {
                    $(".student_time_" + v.share_to).parent().show();
                } else {
                    $(".teacher_time_" + v.share_to).parent().show();
                }
            });
```

finally, at setup the datatable, are there any way to not count the hidden row in the result? e.g. Now the problem is , if total rows are 200, hidden rows are 100, then the datatable shows there are 200 rows.

```
 $('.menu_time_table').DataTable({
                    "order": [[0, "asc"]],
                    "language": table_lang,
                    "bDestroy": true,
                    "deferRender": true
                });
```

Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: Are you using server side or client side datatable ?

Comment: You cannot hide rows through jQuery, hiding a row in the DOM does not hide the row from dataTables. You must use `table.row(<selector>).remove()`

Comment: client side datatable, thanks

Comment: what if I add the class e.g. class="not_show" at those row I would not like to show, can the datatable exclude those row? thanks